# Open JSON files in different directory - Python3, Windows, pathlib

Tags: json, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to open JSON files located in a directory other than the current working directory (cwd). My setting: Python3.5 on Windows (using Anaconda).

```
from pathlib import *
import json

path = Path("C:/foo/bar")
filelist = []
for f in path.iterdir():
    filelist.append(f)

for file in filelist:
    with open(file.name) as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
```

In this setting I have these values:

```
file >> C:\foo\bar\0001.json
file.name >> 0001.json
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
---> 13     with open(file.name) as data_file:
     14         data = json.load(data_file)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0001.json'
```

### Here is what I tried so far:

Use .joinpath() to add the directory to the file name in the open command:

```
with open(path.joinpath(file.name)) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

TypeError: invalid file: WindowsPath:('C:/foo/bar/0001.json')
```

Used .resolve() as that works for me to load CSV files into Pandas. Did not work here.

```
for file in filelist:
    j = Path(path, file.name).resolve()
    with open(j) as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
```

Since I'm on Windows write path as (and yes, the file is in that directory):

```
path = Path("C:\\foo\\bar") #resulted in the same FileNotFoundError above.
```

Instantiate path like this:

```
path = WindowsPath("C:/foo/bar")
#Same TypeError as above for both '\\' and '/'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I am happy to rewrite the question.

Comment: Have you tried using  \  instead of   / . Windows uses the former as the path-delimiter.

Regarding the downvote, that seems rather prevalent here now - downvote anything that doesnt sound good to you and don't even have the courtesy to leave a comment.

Comment: @PranavRai I did and it leads to the same error message. I it seems that the open() command is looking in the cwd instead of the data directory.

Comment: @PranavRai, pathlib does path normalization to replace slash with backslash for a Windows path. (Also, the Windows API allows slash and backslash to be used interchangeably, except raw ``\\?\`` paths require backslash.) The problem here is using the `name` attribute, which is just the base filename, instead of `str(file)`, which is the fully qualified path. In 3.6, pathlib supports the new `__fspath__` protocol, so `open(file)` will work, which will make it simpler to do the right thing.

Comment: Yes, and thanks :) Just came to that realization when working on the debugger

Comment: @eryksun `str(file)` instead of 'file.name' did the trick. I suspected that I am loosing the directory (hence my `joinpath` attempts), but did not consider passing file as a string.

Comment: Having to use `str` prior to 3.6 is a wart because it makes a library's job more difficult than it should be if it wants to support pathlib paths without allowing any object that has an `__str__` representation. That's been standing in the way of adopting pathlib, so the `__fspath__` protocol was added to 3.6 and `os`, `os.path`, and `io` have been updated to support it implicitly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The accepted answer has a lot of redundants - re-collected generator and mixed with statement with pathlib.Path.
pathlib.Path is awesome solution to handle paths especially if we want to create scripts which may work with Linux and Windows.

```
# modules
from pathlib import Path
import json

# static values
JSON_SUFFIXES = [".json", ".js", ".other_suffix"]

folder_path = Path("C:/users/user/documents")
for file_path in folder_path.iterdir():
    if file_path.suffix in JSON_SUFFIXES:
        data = json.loads(file_path.read_bytes())
```

Just adding modification for new users. pathlib.Path works with Python3.

Answer (score 5):

Complete solution; thanks @eryksun:

```
from pathlib import *
import json

path = Path("C:/foo/bar")
filelist = []
for f in path.iterdir():
    filelist.append(f)

for file in filelist:
    with open(str(file) as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
```

This line works as well:

```
with file.open() as data_file:
```